# How to add multiple DoesNotContain text strings to Conditional Formatting VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am looking to add multiple DoesNotContain text strings to this VBA. It may be easier to use a formula here when setting up the conditional formatting, but I am curious if it is possible or easy to add onto this VBA. Thanks in advance!

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="day", _ 
    TextOperator:=xlDoesNotContain
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .color = 12632256
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("A3:A").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
```

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3793-excel-conditional-formatting-search-for-multiple-words.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I have read this doc a few times and I'm not sure if this is what I am looking for. This shows me how to highlight cells using a predefined list in a sheet, whereas I am looking to highlight cells in a range that do not contain certain text or blank cells. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link posted in the comments above...

Put your list of terms in a column and name the range of cells as (eg) "MyTerms"

Add a CF rule which is formula-based using (eg)

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & MyTerms & "*"))=0   'formatting A1:A10
```

That should highlight any cells which don't contain any of the terms in your list.

Comment: Thanks again Tim, I'm not entirely sure why but I had to change the 0 to a 1 and then it worked perfectly!